# Implementing slider with range binded with the number input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, rc-slider

I am using antd slider component . I am trying to implement a range slider which is also binded with two number inputs like the image attached below

[image]

Find my code in the given link https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-framework-xpvl9. On adding range props to the slider component it throws error. I am confused with the logic in implementing min and max in the number inputs binded with the range slider.

```
        <Slider
          className="slider-main-div"
          min={min}
          max={max - 1}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={typeof inputValue === "number" ? inputValue : 0}
        />
        <div className="range-input-number-main">
          <InputNumber
            className="min-input-main"
            min={min + 1}
            max={max - 1}
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={this.onChangeMin}
          />
          <span className="range-span">to</span>
          <InputNumber
            className="min-input-main"
            min={21}
            max={50}
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={this.onChangeMax}
          />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I revised the way you determine the max/min values for the `Input`'s as well as added the `range` property provided by ant design for `Slider`. I also removed `this.state.inputValue` as it doesn't appear to be needed.

Here is the updated `Slider` with `range`.

```
<Slider
          className="slider-main-div"
          min={0}
          max={100}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          range={true}
          defaultValue={[min, max]}
          value={[min, max]}
        />
```

The way you are currently doing it was leading to a stack size error because you were reassigning the max/min values to `this.state.min` and `this.state.max` for the components themselves. So the antd components were updating their initialized props in the render as you changed the `App` state, which then updated the antd component's state while they were re-rendering following the `App` state change,   leading to the stack depth error.

I ended up giving them default values between 0-100 and wrote a conditional in the functions to determine when to set state. For example, in the `onChangeMin` only set the state if the `value` is less than `this.state.max`. Otherwise don't set state. This way the input value for min will never exceed the input value for max.

```
 onChangeMin = value => {
    if (this.state.max > value) {
      this.setState({ min: value });
    }
  };
```

Same for `onChangeMax` but this time comparing `value` to `this.state.min` and making sure it is not less than that.

```
 onChangeMax = value => {
    if (this.state.min < value) {
      this.setState({ max: value });
    }
  };
```

You can find the fully updated code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-cdn-5dwm0).

Comment: Is there a way to show higher range values like 0-500 ?

Comment: @Sofiyarao in the props for min and max just put 0 and 500 respectively